# A way to only allow some ports on windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, security, firewall, port

I have been trying to make this work the last few hours but haven't come far.

I have a windows server 2008 and a set up Local Security Policy
firewall yet "no" inbound rules (yet). My domains look like this:

```
Domain Profile: Inbound = block(default), Outbound = Allow(Default)
Private Profile: Inbound = block(default), Outbound = Allow(Default)
Private Profile: Inbound = block(default), Outbound = Allow(Default)
```

Pretty much default. Now what I want to accomplish is to block all ports except port 80, 443, 53 and a couple of others. In iptables ( on linux ) it is simply accomplished by setting up the ALLOW input rules for the ports and finally a DROP rule to block everything. Now what linux does is preferring an ALLOW rule over a DROP and from what I have understood, windows does not have this setting. So is there a way to mimic this feature?

Comment: No, that is *not* what Linux does. Oy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is modify your Firewall policy so that on an Untrusted (Public) network, the only allowed ports that come in are the ones that you've specified. Disable all other inbound rules.

Presumably your public interface is marked as such, yes?

If, on the other hand, it's sitting on a trusted internal network, you want to do the filtering at the network edge. It's still a good idea to disable inbound ports you don't use, however.